# Is there any way to authorize user via uber app instead of auth 2.0?

Tags: ios, uber-api

We have integrated Uber API in our application. We are requesting uber ride directly from our application which requires authorization token.

We are using below code for authorization,

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] requestAccessToAccountWithType:_applicationName
                               withPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL){

                                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:preparedURL];

                               }];
```

It redirecting to safari and from where user will enter his/her credentials.Control goes back to application and we are getting authorization token. Everything works fine!

Is there any other way through which we can do this within app or via uber application instead of navigating to safari?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the uber in ssl LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and start the url with uber schema uber:// , it will open the uber app if it is installed in the device.

Comment: That we have already done. We want to navigate there and on authentication redirecting back to our app.

Comment: We need to setup a callback uri for that, but I think Uber api doesn't support that as of now.

Comment: Callback is also set. Its working fine in the case of authenticate user for uber via safari. I want to have authentication via uber application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Uber Rides iOS SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk#uber-rides-ios-sdk-beta) which provides a "Ride there with Uber button" that will redirect the user to the Uber app, combined with [API Token / Server Authentication](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#authentication-or-authorization) Uber API endpoints that do not require a user login:
 - GET /v1/products
 - GET /v1/estimates/time
 - GET /v1/estimates/price
you do not need to do user authorization and authentication via OAuth 2.0.

Otherwise, if you need to make requests on behalf of the user using the Uber API, (i.e **without using the Uber app**), you **MUST** implement authorization and authentication using the [OAuth 2.0 protocol flow](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#oauth-20) using with a browser/webview, the Uber app cannot be used for it.

> Before you begin, you should determine what level of access your
>   application needs. Many applications will only use the Products, Price
>   Estimates, and Time Estimates endpoints. For these, you only need to
>   use the server_token to access resources via the API Token
>   Authentication.
>
> If your application will access resources on behalf of an Uber user,
>   such as with the Me and User Activity endpoints, you will need to
>   follow the three-legged OAuth 2.0 flow in order to obtain an
>   access_token.

Comment: We are requesting ride on behalf of the user from the app. So we have to authenticate. All above API which you have mentioned we have already integrated.